# Package Listings Error: File (.m) not found

Tags: listings

So I'm trying to add a Matlab script to my latex document using the **mcode** and **listings** packages. The way I use it is `\lstinputlisting{/Users/Username/Documents/MATLAB/exampleintegral.m}` 
I then get the error "Package Listings Error: File /Users/Username/Documents/MATLAB/exampleintegral(.m) not found"
If I have the .m file in the same folder as the latex file it will retrieve it, but some of the lines will continue over the edge of the page even if I use `\lstinputlisting[breaklines=true]{exampleintegral.m}`.
The weird thing is that I used this method when writing my thesis and it worked like a charm. Now, all of a sudden, the program is unable to find any files.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any solutions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document} 
\lstinputlisting{/Users/User name/Documents/MATLAB/cosmology/exampleintegral.m} 
\end{document}
```

What I use to get around this (by having the code in the same folder as the tex file), although the code will look nasty (some lines break some don't).

`\lstinputlisting[breaklines=true]{exampleintegral.m}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short **compilable** code you have tried so far?

Comment: Does your username contain any special characters or spaces? But as Kurt says it would be easier for us to help you if you could add a MWE (minimal, compilable code example).

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting code in comments. There is an *edit* link right above the comments. After pasting the code into the question, select it and hit Ctrl + K (or click the button marked `{}`).

Comment: Is the space in `user name` also in your real user name?

Comment: In which folder is your tex file?

Comment: @samcarter Yes the space is in my actual username as well. The tex file is located in the Documents folder. As I said, if I place the matlab code in the same folder it will read it as I don't need the whole path, just the name of the file. The issue is that some of the lines will not break and  lines will not break.

Comment: @Vlad can you try with `\lstinputlisting{./MATLAB/cosmology/exampleintegral.m} `? Lines not breaking is another question - please only ask one question per question.

Comment: @samcarter That worked, no more error. Seems like the username is indeed the problem. Weird that the space isn't an issue when locating pictures. Anyways, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space in the absolute file path. There are several ways to avoid this problem, e.g.:

- using a relative file path instead of a total one, i.e. using `\lstinputlisting{./MATLAB/cosmology/exampleintegral.m}` instead of `\lstinputlisting{/Users/User name/Documents/MATLAB/cosmology/exampleintegral.m}`
- using the [grffile](https://ctan.org/pkg/grffile?lang=de) package